# What is package information in Jfrog artifactory and how to populate it?

Tags: maven, artifactory

I use Jfrog Artifactory Community Edition, I deployed a jar artifact of my project into our Artifactory server via Eclipse maven tools (mvn clean deploy) and here is some part of my project's POM file :

```
<modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
    <groupId>org.dpdouran.infrastructure</groupId>
    <artifactId>WebInfra</artifactId>
    <packaging>jar</packaging>
    <version>6.0.3</version>
    <name>WebInfra</name>
    <description>git commit id : -${git.commit.id.abbrev}</description>
```

The question is when I open Jfrog UI and click on specified jar, I can't see 'description' tag in the ui ?
another thing that is shown in that page is `Package Information` which is empty! how can I fill that in my pom file ?
you can see this pic to find out what I mean :
[image: jfrog artifactory artifact page]

Comment: I was just having the same question. No information on that in the docs.

Answer (score 0):

The Package Information tab was used to display package information from Bintray.

Due to the [sunset of Bintray](https://jfrog.com/blog/into-the-sunset-bintray-jcenter-gocenter-and-chartcenter/), this tab should be deprecated.